# Laravel: Inline custom error message using Validator::extend

Tags: laravel, validation

Following: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#using-closures

I have added below code in myServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
    \Validator::extend('foo', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        if('fname' === $value)
        return true;
        return false;            
    });       
}
```

Now, for custom error message what does this line mean? `using an inline custom message array`

what should be the syntax?

> Defining The Error Message
>
> You will also need to define an error
> message for your custom rule. You can do so either using an inline
> custom message array or by adding an entry in the validation language
> file. This message should be placed in the first level of the array,
> not within the custom array, which is only for attribute-specific
> error messages:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to define it globally, you need to edit the validation file lang-path/validation.php.

```
return [
    'foo'             => 'The :attribute must be foo.'
]
```

For locally, you can define it within a Request.

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'foo' => 'The :attribute is not foo.'
    ];
}
```

Comment: can you tell me why the `$parameters` are there when it comes empty always?

Comment: $parameters you need to pass, by default it'll be empty, assume foo is the validation so you can pass foo:10 so $parameters will come as an array with 10 as first element.